# string editing on specific request split.upper/.lower

Tags: python, split, symbols, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to figure out how to edit the below to have a option to convert lower/upper(abc = ABC) I'd like to have a specific input that it knows to convert to the other. so input might be "convert_upper" the program now knows I want to convert the next input "abc" into " 'A', 'B', 'C' "

I've made it pretty far into this endeavor through forums but figuring out how to get the input1 to take a "special request"  and do upper/lower based on that input has thrown me for loop
Also I was curious how I can create the list.  (a 2nd input that confirms the name for the list something like . . . )

example in/output^

```py
input1 = numbers
 numbers = [] 
input2 = 123
numbers = ['1', '2', '3']
```

current code takes input  such as "abc 123 !@#" and outputs a list ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', '1', '2', '3', ' ', '!', '@', '#']

```py
def split(word):
    return list(input1)
input1 = input("enter Letters, Numbers or Symbols: ")
print(split(input1))
```

Comment: You can use `list('your_string')` to convert it to list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach: have a function that you apply to the input, and check for "special requests" to change it:

```
special_requests = {
    "convert_upper": str.upper,
    "convert_lower": str.lower,
    "vanilla": str
}
func = str

while True:
    i = input("? ")
    if i in special_requests:
        func = special_requests[i]
    else:
        print(func(i))
```

```
? abc123
abc123
? convert_upper
? abc123
ABC123
```

Comment: @Samwise that works great for upper/lower. I just need to add split to convert to ['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: You can easily add new entries to the `special_requests` dictionary, e.g. `"split": list`, and it will work just like it does for the other functions.

Comment: @Samwise Okay I've made edits to your suggested code for my own readability and I'm curious is there a way to do upper/lower with split?   ```python special_request = {
    "UPPER": str.upper,
    "LOWER": str.lower,
    "vanilla": str,
    "split": list
    }
func = str
while True:
    i = input("enter Letters, Numbers or Symbols: ")
    if i in special_request:
        func = special_request[i]
    else:
        print(func(i))
```

Comment: I can't really read the code you pasted into the comment, but sure, you could do `"UPPERSPLIT": (lambda s: list(s.upper()))` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you right but there is a **specific method to turn strings into uppercase**, which works like

```
my_upper_string = 'my_string'.upper()
print(my_upper_string)
```

So for example:

```
print('abc'.upper())
```

will print 'ABC'.

Also, consider not re-defining a built-in python function. `split()` exists already with strings. I'd recommend to use another name to avoid weird behavior.

Comment: everytime I try to run split without the one listed above the output is ['abc'] opposed to ['a', 'b', 'c']   The attempt without the above code was... ```python input1 = input("enter Letters, Numbers or Symbols: ")
print(input1.split(' ',)) ```

Comment: That is because with `split()` you can literally split a string by means of a contained character. If you just write `split(' ')`, you split 'abc' nowhere because it doesn't contain any whitespaces. So you don't really need the method here at all. Just go on using `list('abc')` if you want to have the single characters in a list.